Intuition behind the different order of indices under basis transformation
Following Wikipedia, let $B_{\rm old} = \{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n \}$ be a set of basis vectors. Then, under a transformation $A$ a basis vector $v_i \in B_{\rm old}$ transforms as
$$ w_j = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_{i,j} v_i. \qquad (1)$$
where $w_j$ belongs to the set $B_{\rm new} = \{ w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n\}$ of new basis vectors. Cut to the transformation of components, we find
$$ x_i = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} a_{i,j} y_j \qquad (2)$$
Now if we switch the indices $i \leftrightarrow j$ in $(2)$, we obtain
$$ x_j = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_{j,i} y_i \qquad (3)$$
It is clear that while a basis vector $v_i$ transforms with coefficient $a_{i,j}$, the  component $y_i$ transforms with $a_{j,i}$. I want to understand how to remember these two orders and whether there is an intuitive way of understand this difference in the order of indices.

I think about this as follows: Matrix multiplication should work nicely and it is described by its action on components, so there we have $a_{j, i} y_i$ (note that the neighbouring $i$'s cancel). On the other hand, the way the basis vectors transform is rarely relevant and is the "wrong" way around.
